# Reduced profile page

Tags: discussion, support, bug, profile-page

The new profile page shows each paragraph in a single line and restricts the length of it drastically.  Is it intended to continue with this reduced representation? For my profile page it means that I have to move the content to some external non-SO source.

(Edit) more specifically, on some instances of FF I see the [Read more] button (which is fine), but on some (FF 66.0.3 with rev 2021.9.1.40124) I don't.

Comment: Your profile page's looking splendid :) I wonder when SE stops putting `max-width` on elements and finally embraces the stretching. Seems related to [these changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369276/we-ve-shipped-some-changes-to-the-user-profile-navigation) announced on MSE

Comment: What are those very lengthy dots on your profile? "…………………………… ..."? They don't look like the normal horizontal bar you get with `---`.

Comment: @Scratte: intended.

Comment: Ahh.. I see. If you intend to make them very long, then why complain that they are very long?

Comment: @Scratte: The problem was that the [Read more] box is not shown (on some instances of FF).

Comment: It is also worth noting that SE's policy for browser support is "the last two stable versions of the browsers", so if you are on FF 66 (whatever the reasons - I understand it's frustrating, but that's how things are right now), it is likely that the problem will not be addressed at all.

Comment: Current GA Firefox is 91.0.2 on mainstream platforms — FF 66 is antique.

Comment: Still, the sentiment stands. Two **or more** stable versions out of date and you're out of luck.

Comment: Arguably less than a month ago the latest FF ESR version was still 78, which makes 66 not *that* far away if we take it relatively to the current 91 version.

Comment: @Scratte: Removed the ellipses, but the problem pertains...

Comment: My Firefox says I'm at version "91.0.2 (64-bit)" and I'm seeing the "Read more" button on that. I'm not using any experimental version. (It took me a while to realize that FF means Firefox. Consider not using the abbreviation). Assuming this is a bug in the Firefox version you mentioned, then it would make sense to update, no? I mean that's usually what happens if there is a bug and it gets fixed. A newer version is released.

Comment: What is FF? Is it a linux distribution?

Comment: @10Rep **F**ire**F**ox

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that this issue only appears when using a version of Firefox from [almost two and a half years ago](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/66.0.3/releasenotes/) (and which has predated the current ESR version for [almost two years](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Release_Management/Calendar)), and that everything works properly in modern browser versions?